# R.java is not getting generated

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, r.java-file

I have been trying this for the whole day, trying all given solutions on stackoverflow. One last hope is finding an error in my xml file(corresponding to activity) which I am not able to detect. So here I am including all the XML files, please tell me if there is some mistake somewhere?

main.xml (corresponding to Main.java)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/android_bck"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        style="@style/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to App!" >
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connectBtn"
        style="@style/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
        android:text="Connect" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/disconnectBtn"
        style="@style/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
        android:text="Disconnect" >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" " >
    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/pairedDeviceList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="60"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/icon2"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >
    </ListView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
        android:background="@drawable/icon2" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

controls.xml(corresponding to Controls.java)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/neon"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="T1" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="@style/layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="T5" >
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="T2" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="@style/layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="T6" >
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="T3" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="@style/layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="T7" >
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="T4" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="@style/layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="T8" >
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            style="@style/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Fan 1" >
        </TextView>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip" >
        </SeekBar>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            style="@style/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Fan 2" >
        </TextView>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip" >
        </SeekBar>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            style="@style/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Fan 3" >
        </TextView>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip" >
        </SeekBar>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the "styles.xml" in res/values which i have applied on the button's style property:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>
<style name="text">
    <item name="android:padding">4dip</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>

</style>

<style name="layout">
<item name="android:padding">4dip</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:background">#C0C0C0</item> 
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <!--for transparent background> -->

</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Please indent your files.

Comment: Check the Android console. There will usually be an error message for the cause when R.java is unable to generate.

Comment: @ASP Checked..nothing of the sort! All names begin with small letters and contain no special characters.

Comment: @dcharms The Android console is blank

Comment: @HAR I guess so, I added it using the properties panel.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are looking at the Android console, and not the DDMS console right? I just tried it myself and an xml error or naming error both caused error output when it attempts to build.

Comment: @dcharms Yes, Windows->Show View-> Console..which error is it,does it show where the naming error is occurring ?

Comment: @ASP Nope, there is no default.png

Answer (score 0):

if you do not have errors in your project try to clean it.
project menu -> clean

or delete the R.java file

also try the android lint to show all warnings, try to fix it.

[image]

Comment: @EngSamerT This is exactly one of the things I have been doing the whole day!

Comment: Actually its an old version 2.3.1(API level 9)

Comment: To add to the information, i have been working on updating it. It got updated but ADT didn't so I got the error **This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.2 or above.  Current version is 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841.  Please update ADT to the latest version.** Hence I had to resort to the old copy of SDK. These are the various things that I have tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328164/adt-plugin-is-not-updating

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify the style.xml file, I used the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.

        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="textt">
        <item name="android:padding">4dip</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

    <style name="layoutt">
        <item name="android:padding">4dip</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
        <item name="android:background">#C0C0C0</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <!-- for transparent background> -->

    </style>

</resources>
```

and generate missing icons and backgrounds with given names as specified in other xml files, the result is that R.java is generated for me. so I think your problem could by in style.xml