# Errors in updating the Android's ADT Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt, helios

I have been trying everything since 2 days now, my ADT plugin is not updating:

[image]

1)I have tried going to SDK manager in my Android SDK Windows folder, Ran it as Administrator and installed  **Android SDK Build-tools** but going to Windows>Preferences>Android I am still getting the error on selecting this sdk as SDK Path (**This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.2 or above.  Current version is 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841.  Please update ADT to the latest version.**):

[image]

2) And also went to **Help->Check for Updates** but got the error: **Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.7.0' but it could not be found**

[image]

[image]

3) Also going to **Help-> Install new software** and give the path as https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ gives me **Duplicate Location** . Also tried using an http instead of https but to no avail.
[image]

4)Also this is a snapshot of my installation details:

[image]

5) Also manually installed the missing plugins - org.eclipse.core.runtime.3.7.0 and placed it in plugun folder inside eclipse folder. But the software is not reading it.

I dont know what the fault is. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this link: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting

1. download adt from https://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.6.2.zip
2. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
3. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
4. In the Add Repository dialog, click Archive.
5. Select the downloaded ADT-22.6.2.zip file and click OK.
6. Enter "ADT Plugin" for the name and click OK.
7. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
8. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
9. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
10. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

Comment: This was very useful. I went till step 8 but then I got an error that says : **"Your original request has been modified.
 "Android DDMS" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead. "Android Development Tools" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead. Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 22.6.2.v2014 Missing requirement: Core Runtime 3.7.0.v20110110 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.7.0.v20110110) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.osgi 3.7.0' but it could not be found**

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is marked as answered, however I think when you faced too many difficulties in updating process, it is better to download a new copy of "SDK ADT Bandle" from this link.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Yes finally I am reinstalling Eclipse and the original sdk that I had  and this time I shall not update the SDK or ADT!